# How can I improve my chances of a successful platelet donation?

Tags: blood, blood-donation

I have a high platelet count and would love to put that to good use by donating platelets. But the last several times I've tried to give, my veins failed one way or another. The volunteers couldn't get the needle placed successfully, or once they did, it started leaking or losing draw pressure.

I've had successful donations in the past. I've tried abstaining from caffeine and drinking extra non-caffeinated fluids in the 48 hours prior to donation. I don't take aspirin. Is there anything else I can do to improve my vein quality to make a successful donation more likely?